# Падает deploy через jenkins - ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [1]]

Tags: java, jenkins, wildfly

Скорее всего проблема Wildfly. Лог jenkins с настройками:

[TEST_test_appsrv_UI_DEPLOY] $ /bin/bash -xe /tmp/jenkins6293386889713476318.sh
    + rm -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TEST_test_appsrv_UI_DEPLOY/tmp/ar-ui/target/ar-ui.war
    + mv /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TEST_test_appsrv_UI_DEPLOY/tmp/ar-ui/target/ar-ui-0.4-SNAPSHOT.war /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TEST_test_appsrv_UI_DEPLOY/tmp/ar-ui/target/ar-ui.war
    SSH: Connecting from host [avk-jenkins]
    SSH: Connecting with configuration [arfix-appserver-test-deployer] ...
    SSH: EXEC: STDOUT/STDERR from command [chown deployer:wildfly ar-ui.war
    while true ; do
        if [ -f ar-ui.war.isdeploying ]; then
            break
        fi
        sleep 1
    done
    while true ; do
        if [ ! -f ar-ui.war.isdeploying ] && [ -f ar-ui.war.deployed ]; then
            break
        fi
        if [ ! -f ar-ui.war.isdeploying ] && [ -f ar-ui.war.failed ]; then
            echo "DEPLOYMENT ERROR"
            echo "LAST 300 ROWS FROM LOG /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log"
            tail /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log -n 300
            exit 1
            break
        fi
        sleep 1
    done] ...
    DEPLOYMENT ERROR
    LAST 300 ROWS FROM LOG /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log
        jboss.node.name = arfix-appserver-test
        jboss.qualified.host.name = arfix-appserver-test
        jboss.server.base.dir = /opt/wildfly-12.0.0.Final/standalone
        jboss.server.config.dir = /opt/wildfly-12.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration
        jboss.server.data.dir = /opt/wildfly-12.0.0.Final/standalone/data
        jboss.server.deploy.dir = /opt/wildfly-12.0.0.Final/standalone/data/content
        jboss.server.log.dir = /opt/wildfly-12.0.0.Final/standalone/log
        jboss.server.name = arfix-appserver-test
        jboss.server.persist.config = true
        jboss.server.temp.dir = /opt/wildfly-12.0.0.Final/standalone/tmp
        line.separator =

```
    logging.configuration = file:/opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties
    module.path = /opt/wildfly/modules
    org.jboss.boot.log.file = /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log
    org.jboss.resolver.warning = true
    org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Linux
    os.version = 4.4.0-141-generic
    path.separator = :
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.class.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/classes
    sun.boot.library.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = 
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.command = /opt/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar -mp /opt/wildfly/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/opt/wildfly -Djboss.server.base.dir=/opt/wildfly/standalone -c standalone.xml
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level = unknown
    user.country = RU
    user.dir = /opt/wildfly-12.0.0.Final
    user.home = /opt/wildfly
    user.language = ru
    user.name = wildfly
    user.timezone = Europe/Moscow
```

...
    2019-07-04 16:15:41,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
    2019-07-04 16:15:42,031 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (MSC service thread 1-6) Resource adaptor started
    2019-07-04 16:15:42,032 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-6) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatoractivemq-ra
    2019-07-04 16:15:42,035 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
    2019-07-04 16:15:42,036 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
    2019-07-04 16:15:42,203 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
    2019-07-04 16:15:42,208 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990/management
    2019-07-04 16:15:42,209 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
    2019-07-04 16:15:42,209 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 12.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 4.0.0.Final) started in 7484ms - Started 349 of 571 services (327 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
    2019-07-04 16:17:31,944 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location /opt/wildfly-12.0.0.Final/standalone/data/content/21/3ae05cf5f031e067e1500661881931985118d5/content
    2019-07-04 16:17:31,987 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "ar-ui.war" (runtime-name: "ar-ui.war")
    2019-07-04 16:17:41,829 WARN  [org.jboss.as.logging] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYLOG0011: The configuration file in 'logging.properties' appears to be a J.U.L. configuration file. The log manager does not allow this type of configuration file.
    2019-07-04 16:17:42,030 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
    2019-07-04 16:17:42,033 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
    2019-07-04 16:17:42,214 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 12.1)
    2019-07-04 16:17:42,217 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWELD0013: Deployment ar-ui.war contains CDI annotations but no bean archive was found (no beans.xml or class with bean defining annotations was present).
    2019-07-04 16:17:42,296 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = ar-ui.war_oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver_12_1
    2019-07-04 16:17:42,461 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Bastille' 9.1.6.Final
    2019-07-04 16:17:42,806 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
    2019-07-04 16:17:43,034 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 86) Initializing AtmosphereFramework
    2019-07-04 16:17:43,102 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 86) Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@246d396d, ru.avk.ApplicationWebXml@1c27e82e]
    SSH: EXEC: completed after 34 242 ms
    SSH: Disconnecting configuration [arfix-appserver-test-deployer] ...
    ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [1]]
    Build step 'Send files or execute commands over SSH' changed build result to FAILURE
    Finished: FAILURE

Как иправить проблему с тем, что падает сборка в Jenkins?

Comment: Вопрос решен. Проблема в БД. Она недоступна (лежит).

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. Проблема в БД. Она недоступна (лежит).
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor.